# hook_help() isn't recognized in my custom module

Tags: hooks, 9

I created a custom module in Drupal 9.3.8 which implements `hook_help()` using code similar to what I have seen in other modules.

This is the relevant code in the *node_usage.module* file.

```php
function node_usage_help($route_name, RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
  switch ($route_name) {
    case 'help.page.node_usage':
      $text = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/README.md');
      // …
      break;
  }
}
```

The help text doesn't show up on the *Extend* page or on /admin/help after I install it. If I call `$this->moduleHandler->getImplementations('help')` from within the help module, I don't see my module coming up in the list of modules  that implements `hook_help()`. I've tried setting a breakpoint in `token_help()` in the token module, and it does break there when I clear caches.

Why isn't `node_usage_help()` invoked?

The module is otherwise working OK and other hooks are invoked.